# How to select text in a form input when given focus?

Tags: javascript

How can you select the text in a form input when the input is given focus?

```js
$('#my-input').on('focus', function(){
  alert('TODO: select the text');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="my-input" value="Select me on click">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`HTMLInputElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement)`.select()`

```js
$('#my-input').on('focus', function(){
  this.select();
});

$('#clickbutton').click(function(){
     $('#my-input')[0].focus();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="my-input" value="Select me on click">

<button id="clickbutton" value="Focus input and select" >Focus input and select</button>
```